# platform-dependent GUI vs web-interfaces

Tags: user-interface

I have some code written in python for scientific purposes. Now, I am thinking of creating GUI to make it more convenient to use for students. Nowadays, I have a feeling that web-interface based on CGI beats common platform-dependent GUIs based on Qt etc. Could you, please, express your opinion about modern trends in GUI development. What are proc and contras of web user interfaces comparing to others? What are most popular programming tools for developing such GUIs.

Comment: Look at client-side web frameworks like Angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One could write a lot on this topic. Briefly, though, a web based application offers the following benefits (among others):

- You don't have to install the application on every user's PC that wants to use it. They only need their browser and the web location
- If you need to fix a bug in the code or to enhance it, you just do it once and the users benefit from it without you having to "redeploy" the app on all the PCs (related to the first benefit)
- It's easier to set up sharing of data between the users, which can be done from the server side.
- The number available tools for web-based development is growing rapidly, and a lot of it is free or cheap.

The disadvantage of a web-based application, in your case, is that it will likely more effort and learning to get from where you are now (some text-based Python scripts) to a web-based application. Especially once you deal with handling setting up private data management for users (if that's needed), etc. That depends upon the nature of the application and how data is regarded (e.g., is it managed over time, or is it transitory just for the usage session). Whereas to get to a client-based PC GUI app is a matter of using any of a number of GUI libraries available for Python. Once you do the work, though, for the web based application, my opinion is you benefit more from the knowledge of doing the web based application, if that is of interest. It really depends upon your objective (e.g., short term or long term).

Those are just some key thoughts. I'm sure there are other good opinions and inputs.